# Error adding App Engine module in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

I'm getting this error when adding the App Engine with GCM module to my project in Android Studio (v. 0.8.9)

Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':backend:appengineSdk'.
Could not download artifact 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.8:appengine-java-sdk.zip': No cached version available for offline mode

Comment: do you have the java SDK  for appengine ?

Comment: I think it should be downloaded by android studio when adding the module. Anyway, I downloaded the App Engine sdk but how can I reference it in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the problem happened because of the jdk.
I installed the JDK 8, but appengine requires JDK 7.

So, I have uninstalled JDK 8 and installed JDK 7, and everything went fine.